# get the index of multi dimension array , with value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the index of an array without foreach. this is sample array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [gcr_distance] => 31.0
            [gcr_id] => 23
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [gcr_distance] => 28.0
            [gcr_id] => 22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [gcr_distance] => 26.0
            [gcr_id] => 20
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [gcr_distance] => 110.0
            [gcr_id] => 21
        )

)
```

suppose if my data is **gcr_id=21**, by comparing with the above array it should give me **an index of array** **3**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). `array_column` returns all the values which have a key of `'gcr_id'` and then `array_search` returns the key which corresponds to a value of `21`.

```
$array = array(
    array('gcr_distance' => 31.0, 'gcr_id' => 23),
    array('gcr_distance' => 28.0, 'gcr_id' => 22),
    array('gcr_distance' => 26.0, 'gcr_id' => 20),
    array('gcr_distance' => 110.0, 'gcr_id' => 21)
);

$key = array_search(21, array_column($array, 'gcr_id'));
echo $key;
```

Output:

```
3
```

Inspired by @Elementary's comment, I did some bench testing on this. What I found was that on a 100k entry array, `array_search` and `array_column` took around 80% of the time that a `foreach` based search took when the entry was not in the array, 95% of which was in the call to `array_column`. So it would seem that on average, a `foreach` based search would be faster.

Comment: This comment is not for @Nick as your answer is great and no matter what we say you just answered the OP question.This comment is for the OP himself :Hi.I understand your question.However do you know that if the key your are searching is in the first case and the length of your array is for example 1000000 or more you will make your server work for absolutely nothing. It will execute array_column first and then array_search

Comment: for the OP:I think that in some cases foreach is the better solution.Think about it....

Comment: @Elementary I updated my answer with some benchmarking data fyi

Comment: Great answer, I toyed around for a while to see if I could come up with something faster/different. This is the clear winner.

Comment: Good job... Your answer was/is great no matter what we say. I hope the OP will do an optimal choice according to the length of his array because this is not necessarly the solution for every search...